# Is it possible without using any array to assign value of an integer to a designated address?

Tags: c, pointers, assign

I'm recently reading about pointers in C but stuck at a point. I need to provide an example to make the question more clear.

I have declared two integer variables as a and b and assigned values 55 and 88 to them. Now by using the & symbol I can access their address and declare pointers as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 55;
    int b = 88;

    int *pa = &a;
    int *pb = &b;

    printf("Address of 'a' is: %p\n", &a);
    printf("Address of 'b' is: %p\n", &b);

    printf("Desired new address for the value of 'b' is: %p\n", (pa+1));

    //What to do here to assign the value of b into the address (pa+1) ?
}
```

What I try to achieve(without using any arrays) is that: I want the value of b to be assigned to the address next to a.

I can obtain the address of a by &a or *pa = &a and the next address would be (pa+1). Now the pointer pa holds the address to the variable a. And so the value of (pa+1) I guess should point the address of the next possible address of a.

Now my problem is having the value of b and the address (pa+1) how can we register/assign the value of b to the address (pa+1)?

edit:

Following doesn't work:

```
int a = 55;
int b = 88;

int *pa = &a;
int *pb = &b;

printf("Address of 'a' is: %p\n", &a);
printf("Address of 'b' is: %p\n", &b);

printf("Desired new address for the value of 'b' is: %p\n", (pa+1));

*(pa + 1) = b;

printf("New address of 'b' is now: %p\n", &b);
```

Outputs:

[image]

**Solved:**

```
    int main(void)
    {
        int a = 55;
        int b = 88;
        int c;

        int *pa = &a;
        int *pb = &b;

        printf("Address of 'a' is: %p\n", &a);
        printf("Address of 'b' is: %p\n", &b);

        printf("Desired new address for the value of 'b' is: %p\n", (pa+1));

        *(pa + 1) = b;

       printf("New value at pa+1 is now: %d\n", *(pa+1));

}
```

Comment: It seems you want to assign a new address to `b`. This is not possible. The address of any variable is decided by the compiler and cannot be changed. If a is next to b you cannot simply squeeze another value in between. You can only ever assign a new value via an address but you can never change this address.

Comment: No I want to assign the "value of b" to the address pa+1

Comment: The question explicitly says "value of"

Comment: But you print says "Desired new address for the value"

Comment: Are you aware that local variables in functions are likely to be stored on the stack in order of decreasing addresses? `b` has a lower address than `a`.

Comment: "value of b" not b

Comment: *No I want to assign the "value of b" to the address pa+1* That implies to me that you want to change the value of `pa + 1`.  The value of `pa + 1` is an address.  It exists where it exists.  If you want to change the value **at** the address of `pa + 1`, that's `*(pa + 1) = b;` as stated by others - and that's also undefined behavior.  What **exactly** do you mean?

Comment: The value of b is stored at the address of b. That's why it is the value of b. If you want to change the address of a value this is same as change the address of the variable that has this value. BTW: Why do you print the "new address of b" if you expect the *value* of b to change?

Comment: What is the difference between "value of b" and "b"? Those normally mean the same

Comment: All I want to do is this: I want to read the value stored at b. Then I want to put this value at the address pa+1. Is this still not clear?

Comment: I got it now, my question was confusing things up. I edited  with the solution. Thanks for patience.

Comment: *All I want to do is this: I want to read the value stored at b. Then I want to put this value at the address pa+1. Is this still not clear?* As others have stated, that's just `*( pa + 1 ) = b;`

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think that's what he wanted to do but he was printing the wrong things, either that or he wanted to change where b pointed to not sure.

Answer (score 1):

To write a value to an address, you use `*address = value;`.

For example,

```
*(pa + 1) = b;
```

However, by doing this, you are very likely to overwrite some piece of memory that was supposed to be used for something else, and crash your program.

---

Your edit to the question makes it apparent that you want to change the address of a variable. This is impossible. If it was possible, it would be written like `&b = pa + 1;`.

Comment: @floppy380 Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have `(pa+1)` which is an address of type `int *`, so all you need to do is dereference it:

```
*(pa+1) = b;
```

You can then subsequently print that value like this:

```
printf("valud=%d\n", *(pa+1));
```

Note however that what you're doing, writing past the memory bounds of an object, is not allowed by the C standard and in fact invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Such code is only useful when attempting to execute an attack such as a buffer overflow.

Comment: @floppy380 Please include an explanation of exactly what you are trying to accomplish and what the expected behavior is, keeping in mind the undefined nature of what you are doing.

Comment: I want to write the value of b to an adress I define. In this case to the adsress pa+1

Comment: @floppy380 Which this code does.  Why do you think the address of a variable would change just because you wrote the value it contains elsewhere?

Comment: Im working on it just a minute I want to assign the value of b not the b. Maybe I should use int c = b; and then use c

Comment: @floppy380 You need to be more clear on **exactly** what you're expecting.  Perhaps you want to read `*(pa+1)?  Also, please detail **why** you are doing this in the first place and what you hope to accomplish by doing so.  It may lead to a better answer.

Comment: Yes I updated the solution it was my confusing mind,

Answer (score 0):

To write the value of `b` to the address you want you need to use:

```
*(pa + 1) = b
```

But bare in mind that this causes undefined behaviour so you may get what you want or you may not, no way of knowing for sure.

This way you will write the value but the address of `b` won't change, that's why in your print you don't see any difference.

Comment: I want to assign the "value of b" to the address pa+1 not the b itself. Maybe I should use int c = b; and then use c

Comment: @floppy380 you are assigning the value of b... try to print ```*(pa + 1)``` and you see that you will find ```88``` (if it doesn't crash due to undefined behaviour)

Comment: @floppy380 the **value** of ```b``` is ```88```, the **address** of ```b``` is ```0060FEF0``` or whatever your program puts the variable into.